Movie about people training to fight aliens and ultimately killing them all
I watched a movie that I can't remember the name of.
I know that it was about these people finding aliens and thinking that they were evil, so they had this training academy in space on a satellite. They practiced shooting each other in a strange room with lots of crazy angles and flashing lights.
Near the end of the movie, they went and killed off every one of the aliens, except for one. Then, the main character (who I think was finally convinced that they were doing the right thing) went down to the ground and found the last one. Shortly after he discovered that it was actually quite friendly, it died, making him heartbroken with guilt.
This was a live-action movie and I watched it about two or three years ago.  

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title (and any other additional detail that may help identification).

Ender's Game
IMDb:

Young Ender Wiggin is recruited by the International Military to lead
  the fight against the Formics, a genocidal alien race which nearly
  annihilated the human race in a previous invasion.

Detailed plot on Wikipedia here.

Ostensibly in preparation for the expected third invasion, an
  International Fleet (I.F.) is established, with headquarters on Eros.
  Increasingly advanced starships are built and secretly launched to
  attack the buggers' home worlds. To develop commanders capable of
  defeating the much larger bugger forces, the I.F. creates a crash
  training program for children with the best strategic minds, the
  Battle School.
Graff, on hearing of this, offers Ender a place in the Battle School,
  situated in Earth's orbit, where Graff quickly isolates Ender from the
  other cadets.
Instead, Ender joins the colony program to populate one of the buggers' former 
  worlds. There, he discovers the dormant egg of a bugger queen, who
  reveals that the buggers had initially assumed humans were a
  non-sentient race, for want of collective consciousness, but realized
  their mistake too late, and requests that Ender take the egg to a new
  planet to colonize.

Trailer:



You can watch the complete movie with foreign dubbing here:



At ca.0:40:55 in the film above starts the sequence where the cadets enter the battle arena on the space station and pratice combat (shooting, lasers, floating, etc.). Near the end of the movie, ca. at 1:42:55, after the real battle is over, Ender, the main protagonist, goes down to the planet of the aliens and finds the last surviving alien. 
